# Expression for retelling

Tags: expressions

When you want to say : *I'd like to bring not all but some parts of a conversation in here* or *I'd want to retell a conversation* , what would the possible expressions be, instead of retell or bring in?

Comment: tell a conversation is dodgy, so is retelling it. I want to repeat part of a conversation. Unless it's taped, how do you know for sure??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to bring not all but some parts of a conversation in here

> "I'd like to reiterate my previous statement, that …"
>
> "I'd like to repeat my point, that …"

I'd want to retell a conversation ,

**If some time had elapsed (e.g. polite reminder)**

> I would like to recount my previous conversation, where I told you....
>
> I would like to remind you of our previous conversation, where I told you....

**Emphatical (However depending on tone of content may be taken as mild or rude)**

> I already told you, …
>
> I told you, ...

Answer (score 0):

to **restate** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/restate)

> to state again

As in:

> Could you please **restate** that part of X

I also think you use of **retell** is good too, and to **re-visit** is oft used.